# (segfault) Error reading variable, cannot read variable at address X

Tags: c, pointers, greedy

I'm trying to write code for the gas station problem, where you have a fixed number of cities(linear) and you want to get from one end to the other with as few stops as possible, stopping wherever necessary to refill your gas tank. This is my main function; the function for calculation I've left out for now. 
I keep segfaulting saying unable to access tank and arr during the call to solver(the function I'm using to solve).

```
int main(void)
{
    int tank;
    int cities;
    int ans;

    scanf("%d %d",&cities, &tank);
    int *arr;

    arr=(int *)calloc(cities,sizeof(int));
    int *arr2;
    arr2=(int *)calloc(cities,sizeof(int));
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<cities;++i)
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    arr2[i]=0;
    for(i=1;i<cities;++i)
    arr2[i]=arr[i]-arr[i-1];    
    for(i=0;i<cities;++i)
       printf(" %d ",arr2[i]);  


    ans=solver(tank, arr2,cities);
    printf("\n ans is %d",ans);

    return 0;

}
```

Can I get some pointers here(terrible pun)?
I'm using the input as:
6 3
0
1
3
4
7
10

Arr holds [0,1,3,4,7,10]
Arr2 holds the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop statement is the problem because of missing encolsing `{}`:

```
for(i=0;i<cities;++i)      // loop
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);   // but there is no enclosing braces. so this is the only statement that loops
arr2[i]=0;              //<<<<<< this is executed when loop is finished, i.e i==cities
```

In other words, you assign `arr2[cities]`, which is out of bouds as it's indexed from `0` to `cities-1`.  This causes the segfault.

Looking at the rest of the code, I guess you inteded to to:

```
...
for(i=0;i<cities;++i) {    // loop, but for the block 
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);   
    arr2[i]=0; 
} 
...
```

Comment: A good way to prevent this sort of error in the future is to declare the loop variable in the first statement of the loop head: `for (int i = 0; i < cities; ++i) {`. That way, if you try to use `i` after the loop ends, the compiler will complain.

Comment: `arr2[i]` does not even need to be set, as the memory was `calloc`'d

Comment: Actually, it segfaults again. I did make the edit @Christophe. 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004006a4 in solver (
    tank=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7c5cad6b9d6c>, 
    arr=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffbc50>, length=4198430) at gasstation.c:7
7 {

Comment: Christophe, I've made a lot of edits,I'll post the whole thing.

Comment: I solved it myself after editing the code. thank you.